# how to save the contents of a webpage in a file using shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

how to save the contents of a webpage in a file using shell script. Web page is using URL, username and password to open.

```
curl -O odcview:password http://stomv11204:8080/SIM/realGraph.do?componentId=76&filterString=MCRC_STR&tabname=Durables&componentId=75&filterFlag=0&reqtype=de&filterTitle=dname
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) the URL, otherwise the `&` signs will be interpreted as command delimiters. That said, you can either redirect the `curl` output to a file (`curl [...] > index.html`) or use `wget`, which saves to file by default.

Comment: Thanks but this saves the data in html format..How would i  extract a string MCRC which apperars on the web page from this file.I have to  actually extracta word MCRC from the web page and its correponding values .

Comment: @iram please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you need to do. You are asking "how can I save a webpage" not "how do I extract a specific string from the webpage". You need to explain your issue in order to get an answer. If you need help with extracting a string, we need to see the input you want to parse.

Comment: Also, beware the [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)! To get the most useful help, make sure you explain what you are trying to *achieve*, not what you're trying to *do*.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for simple web pages is 'lynx' which has a -dump option. It will save to a file a 'readable' view of the web pages content. 
lynx is a bit old and hairy now, and doesn't support either javascript nor frames. But if your trying to strip out 'human readable' content from a flat low/non-interactive web page, it a bit simpler to work with than curl.

Most Linux distro have lynx as an optional package, so you'll probably have to install it with your versions package manager.

Comment: HI...Lynx command is not working at my end.I want to open a web page using the username and password and then find the occurence of a string MCRC and the corresponding value displayed on web page against it and then save it in text file.